# methods from a protocol is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I got the next problem I have 3 views (a UITableView, and2 View Controller) I made the next 2 protocols : AddViewControllerDelegate and ViewAlarmControllerDelegate:
AddViewController.h :

```
@protocol AddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)addAlarm:(AlarmObject *)alarm;

@end

@interface AddViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <AddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
```

ViewAlarmController.h:

```
@protocol ViewAlarmControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)changeAlarm:(AlarmObject *)alarm atIndex:(int) alarmID;
- (void)deleteAlarmAtIndex:(int) alarmID;

@end

@interface ViewAlarmController : UIViewController
{
    id <ViewAlarmControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;
```

Then in HomeViewController.h I imported as fallow:

```
#import "AddViewController.h"
#import "ViewAlarmController.h"
#import "AlarmObject.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController <AddViewControllerDelegate, ViewAlarmControllerDelegate>
```

And I have the next declaration of methods into HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)addAlarm:(AlarmObject *)alarm{
    [self.items addObject:alarm];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog (@"added");
}

- (void)deleteAlarmAtIndex:(int)alarmID{
    NSLog(@"alarmID: %d", alarmID);
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:alarmID];
    NSLog(@"items: %@", items);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)changeAlarm:(AlarmObject *)alarm atIndex:(int)alarmID{
    NSLog(@"change");
}
```

ViewAlarmController.m the calling of protocol's method code block:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    AlarmObject* alarmObj = [[AlarmObject alloc]init];
    if(![self.alarmNameField.text isEqual: @""]){
        [alarmObj setValue:self.alarmNameField.text forKey:@"alarmName"];
        NSLog (@"change alarm id = %d", alarmID);
        [self.delegate changeAlarm:alarmObj atIndex:alarmID];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)reverse:(id)sender {
    alarmNameField.text = [alarm valueForKey:@"alarmName"];
}

- (IBAction)deleteAlarm:(id)sender {
    NSLog (@"delete alarm id: %d",alarmID);
    [self.delegate deleteAlarmAtIndex:alarmID];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that the addAlarm works but when i go into ViewAlarm and i press the button to delete or save the changes the deleteAlarmAtIndex and changeAlarm methods are not called.

The problem was in the next method:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addAlarmSegue"]){
        AddViewController *avc = segue.destinationViewController;
        avc.delegate = self;
    }else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"viewAlarmSegue"]){
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ViewAlarmController *vac = segue.destinationViewController;
        [vac getObject:[self.items objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row] withId:selectedRowIndex.row];

        vac.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

I didn't wrote `vac.delegate = self;`

Comment: What is important is where you are setting the delegate and whether or not it is nil when you make the calls to those functions. You would want to post that since its probably where your problem is.

Comment: I agree, `delegate` is most likely `nil`.

Comment: I edited the post and added the calling code block. in the same way i called into the addViewController the method from it's protocol and for that it worked.

Comment: yeah I put the delegate into a NSLog and it is null can you help me to figure out why ?

Comment: I can't figure out why in the AddViewController the delegate isn't null and in the ViewAlarmController it is null, because I used the same way to create the protocols, I added both of them and I don't know what I'm missing....

Comment: @user1792771: The way you created the protocols is irrelevant to a variable being null. A protocol is just a list of messages an object can respond to. The problem is that you are not setting the delegate for your ViewAlarmController.

Comment: Thank you after all your comments I figure out where i was wrong thank you very much

Comment: @user1792771 You should add an update to your question explaining the solution. It may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that object which should conforms to your protocol is not `nil`

```
My1Object *a = [My1Object new];
My2Object <Myprotocol> *b = [My2Object new];

a.delegate = b;

@interface My1Object <MyProtocol> 

@property (nonatomic, weak /* or 'unsafe_unretained' for iOS less than 5.0*/) id <MyProtocol> delegate;

@end

@implementation My1Object

...



 - (void)somethingHappened {
     // just for check as I said:
     NSLog(@"self.delegate = %@", self.delegate); // make sure this is not nil!
     if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myProtocolMethod:)]) {
         [self.delegate myProtocolMethod:self];
     }
 }

...

@end
```

Remember that you shouldn't retain (strong) your delegate!